# How to turn off this horizontal line in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting this line whenever i scroll it makes new lines of the code scrolled to come up and it is annoying and I do not know how to fix this.
I have put an image of the same over here. Please help.

I have tried many times to get this solved.

Comment: Cant see your image

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature that holds the start of certain blocks of code while scrolling the content of the block. It is enabled by default. To disable, go to the `View` menu tab and click on `Appearance`. The third item in the fourth block of selectors is titled `Sticky Scroll`. Click on this to remove the tick mark, and you should be back to normal scrolling.