# Visual Studio text editor scrolling problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using VSCode for a year or so and now suddenly there is a strange effect while scrolling. There appears to be a 'fixed' section which doesn't scroll - in the image below, if I scroll then lines 32 + will scroll 'underneath' line 17-18 etc. which stay fixed. The line numbers are confused as well.

[image: screenhot of editor window]

Is this the result of an option setting somewhere? Or should I re-install VSCode (and all its plugins)? Version is 1.87.2, Windows 10

Comment: Right click and then disable "permanent scrolling", this worked for me

Comment: Trun off `sticky scroll` in your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called sticky scroll, and you can switch it off in the settings. More here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_sticky-scroll

Answer (score -1):

This is a feature that holds the start of certain blocks of code while scrolling the content of the block. It is enabled by default. To disable, go to the View menu tab and click on Appearance. The third item in the fourth block of selectors is titled Sticky Scroll. Click on this to remove the tick mark, and you should be back to normal scrolling.

Also answered at [How to turn off this horizontal line in VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78116383/how-to-turn-off-this-horizontal-line-in-vscode) - and others linked to it.

Comment: that link doesn't work anyway! (at least on my browser)

Comment: Apologies, the link that was auto-generated contained some invalid characters. I have corrected it and it should work now.